# Loop with table function in R

Tags: r, loops

I am a very beginner with **R**. I have a question about the table function. I have a result like this :

```
table(my_vector)
1    2   3
11  23   7
```

And I want to extract elements from a matrix :

From 1 to 11 as `my_matrix[1:11,]`

Form 11+1 to 11+23 as `my_matrix[12:34,]`

Form 11+23+1 to 11+23+7 as `my_matrix[35:41,]`

How can I do a loop with this ?

Answer (score 1):

Think this should do it

```
my_matrix <- matrix(rep(1:41, times=3), 41)
my_vector <- rep(1:3, times=c(11, 23, 7))
my_tab <- table(my_vector)

my_csum1 <- c(0, cumsum(my_tab)) + 1
my_csum2 <- cumsum(my_tab)

my_list <- list()
for (i in 1:length(my_csum2)) {
    my_list[[i]] <- my_matrix[my_csum1[i]:my_csum2[i], ]
}
lapply(my_list, range)
# [[1]]
# [1]  1 11

# [[2]]
# [1] 12 34

# [[3]]
# [1] 35 41
```